# map() return doesn't render in react component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to render data in a second render with JSON data mapping over it. I have to look over two objects to find matching `product_ids`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
  { 
    this.props.productGroups.map((productGroup) => {
      return (
        <TabContainer key={productGroup.id}>
          <h3>{productGroup.title}</h3>

          {
            productGroup.product_ids.map((productId) => {
              this.props.products.map((product) => {
                if (product.id == productId) {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      test
                    </div>
                  )
                } else {
                  console.log('miss')
                }
              })
            })
          }

        </TabContainer>
      )
    }) 
  }
```

On a sidenote, I know this is callback hell, just not to sure on the best way of refactoring this.

Comment: try this `productGroup.product_ids.map(function(productId)` and do the same for the next one and do `return`.

Comment: Re the side note, perhaps think about restructuring your product data so it's not an array of product objects, but an object that has product ids for keys. It would mean you wouldn't need to loop over the array - just check to see if the products object contains a specific key or not.

Comment: This is coming from a API. @Andy

Comment: You can still restructure it after you've received the data. Depends if makes your life easier or not I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first .map() is missing a return before `this.props....`

`return this.props.products.map((product) => {`

Comment: Ahah, thank you. Would love an answer to the sidenote too.

Comment: What does your data structure look like? How did you get the productGroup?

Comment: Also, don’t worry about the callbacks, that’s how the language works. I’d be more concerned with what seems to be an O(n^2) operation to show one list of data.

Answer (score 1):

@BenSteward's answer is correct. For your side note, there are various ways to lessen the nested maps.

One way would be, instead of looping through `product_ids` and loop through `products` inside of it, you can just loop through `products` and check if that `product`'s id *exits* in the specified `product_ids`:

*(This is a cleaner version of your code with less `parenthesis` and `braces`)*

```
{
  this.props.productGroups.map(productGroup => (
    <TabContainer key={productGroup.id}>
      <h3>{productGroup.title}</h3>

      {this.props.products.map(product => {
        if (productGroup.product_ids.includes(product.id)) { /* Note this line */
          return <div>test</div>
        }
        console.log('miss')
      })}
    </TabContainer>
  ))
}
```

I'm sure it's much better in performance and also much more understandable to your future self.