# Iterating through an array is not rendering values

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using the code below, but it's not rendering anything the values of my array. I even tested using `<Text></Text>` or other tags. I know that the array is populated because I get results back when I `console.log(imageArray)`.

```
        <View>
        {
            imageArray.map((array, index) => {
                <TouchableOpacity key={index}>
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: array }}
                        style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity >
            })
        }
    </View>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map() return doesn't render in react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970836/map-return-doesnt-render-in-react-component)

Comment: use a `return` statement or remove the arrow function brackets

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are not returning any values while going through the array.

```
 <View>
    {
        imageArray.map((array, index) => {
            return <TouchableOpacity key={index}> <----- Return statement
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: array }}
                    style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity >
        })
    }
</View>
```

There are others ways in which you can accomplish what you are trying to do, but without too much rewrite of your code, a simple return statement while iterating the array should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    or
 <View>
    {
        imageArray.map((array, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={index}>
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: array }}
                    style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity >
        )
    }
</View>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).